# Java Socket files and directory list names display on client

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I want to do a socket connection for client and server to display the list of files, but below code is not taking any input from server or giving output to client. 
Please help.

Server code:

```
 package javaapplicationthread;

    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;



    public class zs {
      public static int reads,red;  
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        { 
                int flg=0;

               try{while(true){ 
                   ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1312);
               Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                             BufferedReader bufferedReader;
           PrintWriter outk=new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);

           bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));


             traverse(inputFolder, "");

        }
               }            
           catch (IOException ex) {
                      System.out.println("my exception is"+ex);
           }  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I see is that you create server socket in while loop. In the second run of the while loop you will eventually get 'java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind'.

Server code shall be as follows:

```
try{
   ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1312);
   while(true) {
       serverSocket.accept();

       //Client connected
       Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

       //Socket read-write
       //Also it is better to delegate this client session to another thread
   }
}catch(IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Secondly your server code reads a String line and sends "abc" to the client and then calls "traverse" metod. But "traverse" method seems to send nothing to the client socket.

Also client gets blocked in the "redd = b.readLine();" line since server just sends "abc" and does not append new line ('\n or \r).